# Rich snippet is not showing for Schema.org/AggregateRating

Tags: schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I use Schema.org "reviews," "aggregateRating," and other markup on my product pages (e.g. http://www.softwareadvice.com/crm/leadmaster-crm-profile/). I get a rich snippet in Google when there is only one review on the page.

However, I cannot get a rich snippet to display for products with more than one review (e.g. http://www.softwareadvice.com/crm/leadmaster-crm-profile/). I have confirmed this by looking in search results, but by also testing this URL in Google's Rich Snippet Testing Tool.

I assume there is some issue with the Schema.org markup. I've tested several variations of the markup, but to no avail.

I'd love to get any Schema.org experts' help with this issue. Would you mind checking out the source of the "leadmaster-crm-profile" URL and letting me know if there is any obvious issue with how we are coding the Schema.org in this page: